# Regex to get the number after a string and stop after a space

Tags: regex

I have strings such as `@unique2 @someOther` and `@unique32 2 or more`

I need regex to extract the number after @unique however i'm having issues when there is only one digit and when there is some more text after the string I'm looking at (i.e. it doesnt stop after the space)

So:
`@unique2 @someOther` should return 2
and
`@unique32 2 or more` should return 32

So I currently have `([^@unique](\d)+)` however doesnt work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong

Comment: (?<=^@unique)(\d+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\@unique(\d+)
```

You can check it at https://regex101.com/r/MAjxN2/1

I don't understand why you're using `[^]` in your regex

Comment: Thanks - but that gives a full match with the word @unique as well
I just want the number part. So do i need `{1}` somewhere?

Comment: You can get the number in captured group

Comment: @xuanduc987: he means lookbehind . detail in :http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html (lookaround)

Comment: So the regex in JS returns an array so i simply used `[1]`. Thanks